# PhoneGap Backbone App Events fire on new view

Tags: javascript, cordova, backbone.js

This is a tricky problem to explain but I will try my best:

**In Short:** I have a Phonegap application that is using Backbone. When a touch event (on element A) is triggered on a view (lets say View A) and that event navigates to a new view (View B). An event is fired on an element (element B) on View B if element B is in the same position as element A.

**Detailed:** As mentioned above, the application makes use of Backbone. The problem only occurs on a mobile device and not on a browser on my machine. I have implemented jQuery Touch events to work with normal jQuery.

*Snippet from my Router:*

```
routes : {
    "cart" : "cart",
    "menu" : "menu"
},
cart: function (args, options) {
    var options = options || {};
    var view = App.Router.loadView(new App.Views.CartView(options), {access:true});
    return view;
},
menu: function (args, options) {
    var options = options || {};
    var view = App.Router.loadView(new App.Views.MenuView(options));
    return view;
},
loadView: function (view, options) {
    var options = options || {},
        returnview = view;

    if (App.view) {
        //Close views and subviews
        _.each(App.view.subViews, function (subView) {
            subView.close();
        });
        App.view.close();
    }
    App.view = returnview;
    return $('#app-content').append(App.view.render().$el);
}
```

*Snippet from MenuView*

```
events: {
    'tap #cart': function () {
        App.Router.navigate('cart', {trigger:true});
    }
},
```

*Snippet from my CartView*

```
'change #article-stock': function (e) {
    alert('this should not happen!')
}
```

The scenario presents itself when I tap on an element on my menu (#cart), which in turn calls navigate, which creates the new view (CartView). CartView has a checkbox that is in the same position as where the #cart element was on the previsou view. When CartView is rendered the checkbox is toggled and I receive the alert, even though there was not event on that view. Its as if the event on the previous view bubbles through to the next view.

I obviously don't intent for this to happen. Does anyone know why this occurs, and how can this be prevented?

I hope I explained the issue well enough.

I have searched for a solution to my problem, but the only results I find are relating to events firing twice on the same view and not a single event firing on multiple views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whilst going through my questions today I saw this one, and thought I would post my solution to this problem if anybody ever has the same issue.

I was never able to fully figure out what the actual cause of the problem was, my guess is that it is just the way the Android browser handles events, but by adding **e.preventDefault();** to my events fixed it:

*Snippet from MenuView*

```
events: {
    'tap #cart': function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        App.Router.navigate('cart', {trigger:true});
    }
},
```

*Snippet from my CartView*

```
'change #article-stock': function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('this should not happen!')
}
```